# How do I get the exact height of an element which the height css attribute is set auto in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm using Reactjs and I want to get the height of an img element, I want to maintain the ratio of the img so I'm setting the image in css like this.

```
.img {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  left: 5%;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

Please noted that the height is "auto" here.

Now I'm simply trying to obtain it's rendered height in componentDidMount() like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const height = document.getElementById('ImgID').clientHeight;
    const width = document.getElementById('ImgID').clientWidth;
    console.log(height, width)
}
```

The I check simply print the result in console but the log shows that height is 0 and width is 252 (explicit width).

[image]

The fact is that the image appeared on the screen and it's height is visually not 0. Then I tried to check attribute 'clientHeight' manually by printing:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('ImgID').attributes)
```

By expanding 'style > ownerElement > clientHeight' I see that the client Height is 49, which is not zero, but I just can't get that correct value :/.

[image]

I'm looking for a solution to get the height in this situation, it can be done be Javascript/css, or both. I tried to avoid JQuery because React is using virtual DOM, not the browser DOM.

-------------------update--------------------

here's what I got with getBoundingClientRect() suggested by the answer from @ııı

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually because the image hasn't loaded yet when `componentDidMount()` executes. The `<img>` is in the DOM, but the `height` is not known until the image loads (unless explicitly set from CSS). Solution is to query the height in `onLoad`. See test below:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    //console.log(this.refs.img.getBoundingClientRect().height);
    console.log('componentDidMount', this.refs.img.clientHeight);
  }
  imageLoaded = () => {
    console.log('imageLoaded', this.refs.img.clientHeight);
  }
  render() {
    return <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" 
                ref="img"
                onLoad={this.imageLoaded}
                />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="http://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```